# Record Aggregation in Mongo across an Array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array stored in each document/record in a mongo database and I need to compute a score for each element in this array and aggregate the scores by another field in the array element.

It's hard for me to explain what I am trying to do in english so here is a python example of what I am looking to do.

```
records = [
    {"state": "a", "initvalue": 1, "data": [{"time": 1, "value": 2}, {"time": 2, "value": 4}]},
    {"state": "a", "initvalue": 5, "data": [{"time": 1, "value": 7}, {"time": 2, "value": 9}]},
    {"state": "b", "initvalue": 4, "data": [{"time": 1, "value": 2}, {"time": 2, "value": 1}]},
    {"state": "b", "initvalue": 5, "data": [{"time": 1, "value": 3}, {"time": 2, "value": 2}]}
]


def sign(record):
    return 1 if record["state"] == "a" else -1


def score(record):
    return [{"time": element["time"], "score": sign(record) * (element["value"] - record["initvalue"])} for element in record["data"]]

scores = []
for record in records:
    scores += score(record)

sums = {}
for score in scores:
    if score["time"] not in sums:
        sums[score["time"]] = 0
    sums[score["time"]] += score["score"]

print '{:>4} {:>5}'.format('time', 'score')
for time, value in sums.iteritems():
    print '{:>4} {:>5}'.format(time, value)
```

This computes a slightly different score function for state `a` and for state `b` and then aggregates the scores across each time entry.

Here is the result

```
time score
   1     7
   2    13
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this in mongo, without pulling the records into python and reinventing aggregation.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I figured this out.  Once I really understood how pipeline's work and about the condition function everything came together.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
result = client.mydb.foo.aggregate([
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'data': 1, 'initvalue': 1, 'state': 1}},
    {'$unwind':  '$data'},
    {'$project': {
        'time': '$data.time',
        'score': {'$multiply': [
            {'$cond':     [{'$eq': ['$state', 'a']}, 1, -1]},
            {'$subtract': ['$data.value', '$initvalue']}
        ]}
    }},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$time',
        'score': {'$sum': '$score'}
    }},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'time': '$_id', 'score': 1}}
])
for record in result['result']:
    print record
```

This yields the desired result

```
{u'score': 13, u'time': 2}
{u'score': 7, u'time': 1}
```

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding the above commands, this might help.  The aggregate function is an array ("pipeline") of commands.  Try removing commands from the end of the array and see how the intermediate-result changes.